# AngularJS ngResource delete event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to keep a list of resources up to date as a user interacts with it. Using an AngularJS ngResource I initially grab the list using it's `query` method. Each resource then has a `$remove` (or `$delete`) method, right? But when fired, the resource isn't removed from the list returned from `query`.

This is asking a lot, I know, but I was almost hoping it would just do everything for me. Save that, how could I accomplish this. Does the resource itself emit some kind of event? Does it have a deleted property I can `$watch`? How would I go about know that a resource was `$remove`'d so I can splice it out of the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that you are referring to?

Comment: It's a real shame it doesn't handle this by itself. It would seem like a staringly obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `Array`'s `splice` method to remove it (`$index` is ng-repeat's implicit index).

```
$scope.removeItem = function (index) {
    $scope.items[index].$delete();
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And then in your HTML

```
<a ng-click="removeItem($index)">remove me</a>
```

Comment: This will work most of the time, but what happens when there is some kind of error server-side. You UI will no longer reflect the correct state.

Comment: then you can pass it as a callback, I think :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the success callback function:

```
instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

For you I am guessing that would be something like:

```
myResource.$delete([parameters], function () {
    //delete was successful
});
```