# ngResource remove record from query object with $delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, notifications

Fairly new to angular. I want to use angular's $resource library to consume our API services. I'm a little lost on the proper way to delete a record obtained via the query() method. Specifically, we have an endpoint for user notifications. We want to, on page load, get all user notifications, use ng-repeat to loop over the results and display the notifications in the nav bar. When a user clicks a remove icon, the corresponding notification should be deleted. Here's the stripped down version of the code I currently have:

Js:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngResource']).factory('Notifications',function($resource){
    return $resource('/apiv2/user/notifications/:id', {id:'@id'});
}).controller('NavigationController',['$scope','Notifications',function($scope, Notifications){
    $scope.notifications = Notifications.query();

    $scope.deleteNotification = function(notification){
        notification.$delete();
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
        <i class="icon-remove" ng-click="deleteNotification(notification)"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this code, when a user clicks on the remove icon, the individual notification object is passed to the deleteNotification method and is properly deleted from the backend via the api. Up until this point, everything works as intended. However, if I look at the $scope.notifications object after the fact, the notification that was just deleted remains with broken data:

{$promise:undefined, $resolved:true}

Ideally, I want this record wiped from the object returned via the .query() method to reflect its state on the back end, without having to do a new .query().

Any help would be appreciated! I apologize for vague descriptions and/or incomplete/innaccurate code, I typed this all from memory via my phones keyboard whilst out at dinner, so god knows if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better way of doing it:** (see [AngularJS ngResource delete event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700788/angularjs-ngresource-delete-event))

```
$scope.deleteNotification = function (index) {
  $scope.notifications[index].$delete();
  $scope.notifications.splice(index, 1);
}
```

and in your markup just do

```
ng-click="deleteNotification($index)"
```

There probably is a better way to do this as this throws a console error (but still works), but this is what I am doing:

```
$scope.notifications = Notifications.query();

$scope.deleteNotification = function(notification){
    notification.$delete();
    $scope.notifications = $scope.notifications.filter( function(n)
        return (n != notification);
    }); // filter everything but
};
```

if you use underscore there is a more beautiful way to write the remove thing.